# Working with multiple browser instances on cucumber+selenium

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, cucumber-java

When using cucumber with selenium, Using TestContext, I was able to launch 1 instance of browser.
[image: the image is of one of the step definitions]

Now I want to launch 2 instances of same browser. So I tried [image] this way.

But this does not launch 2 instances of browser.

How can I launch 2 browser instances while using TestContext.
This is the TextContext file contents:

```
    package cucumber;

import managers.PageObjectManager;
import managers.WebDriverManager;

public class TestContext {
    private WebDriverManager webDriverManager;
    private PageObjectManager pageObjectManager;

    public TestContext(){
        webDriverManager = new WebDriverManager();
        pageObjectManager = new PageObjectManager(webDriverManager.getDriver());
    }

    public WebDriverManager getWebDriverManager() {
        return webDriverManager;
    }

    public PageObjectManager getPageObjectManager() {
        return pageObjectManager;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does this method call - webDriverManager.getDriver() - return the same driver instance or a new driver instance is created?

Comment: This happens..
public WebDriver getDriver() {
  if(driver == null) driver = createDriver();
  return driver;
 }

Comment: I think this is the reason when i run the script, the second browser instance was not launched. @Grasshopper